# How to select friends' data based on the same document?

Tags: mongodb

How to select friends data from the user document. 
EG:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a70c1159d0e9b2c40bfbfed"),
    "name" : "Mo Salah",
    "profile_pic":"(LINK)",
    "d":"d",
    "id" : "1",
    "friends" : [ 

    {
     "id" : "2",
     "name" : "mike",
     "image" : "(LINK)"
     },
    {
     "id" : "3",
     "name" : "Sam",
     "image" : "(LINK)"
     },
    {
     "id" : "4",
     "name" : "John",
     "image" : "(LINK)"
     }

    ]
}
```

I want to search in the users' collection based on the IDs in friends' object/array.

**EDIT**

Output should be like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a70c1159d0e9b2c40bfbmde"),
    "name": "mike",
    "profile_pic":"(LINK)",
    "id" : "2",
    "friends":[{array of his friends too}]
}
```

Comment: Is users a separate collection ? If yes you have to use $lookup operator.

Comment: no, it isn't. In short, I have 1 Collection call users and I wanna create a friending system to allow users to add friends. Since, we are using NoSQL then I have to make the relations manually.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output and input ?

Comment: @Veeram check update